# How to store non-objects in a dictionary?

Tags: objective-c

I tried storing a selector(SEL) in a NSMutableDictionary and it caused a crash, probably because the dictionary tries to dereference it as an object pointer. What is the standard recipe for storing non-objects in a dictionary?

Comment: What is the purpose of storing selectors in dictionary? Just curious.

Comment: for clarity, would you be willing to mark @dreamlax's answer as correct? I arrived here from google looking to store a selector in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them into objects.

Answer (score 15):

You can convert selectors to `NSString` using [`NSStringFromSelector()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_166) and you can go back the other way with [`NSSelectorFromString()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_152).

```
SEL aSel = @selector(takeThis:andThat:);

[myDict setObject:NSStringFromSelector(aSel) forKey:someKey];

SEL original = NSSelectorFromString([myDict objectForKey:someKey]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a [NSMapTable](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSCreateMapTable) with NSObjectMapKeyCallBacks and NSNonOwnedPointerMapValueCallBacks. This works like a NSMutableDictionary but allows any pointers as values, not just objects.

You also could store the selector in a NSInvocation object and use that with a regular dictionary. If you need to store more than the Selector (target, parameters and so on) this is probably the better solution.

Comment: I think `NSMapTable` is only available for Mac OS X, but the OP didn't specify his target platform.